# Abbreviations in a football league table - what do they mean?

Tags: football, terminology

League tables for football often use a series of abbreviations for their columns, like P, W, D, L, GS, GA, +/-, Pts.

What do they all stand for?

Answer (score 11):

Nice and easy:

- P: Games **p**layed
- W: Games **w**on
- D: Games **d**rawn
- L: Games **l**ost
- GS: **G**oals **s**cored
- GA: **G**oals **a**gainst
- +/-: goal difference (ie goals scored minus goals against); often abbreviated to "GD".
- Pts: Points